# Retain the selected value in html.dropdownlist

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a drop down list. How can make the selected value stay selected even after the javascript function is executed. Right now, no matter what option I select, after the javascript function is run, the drop down defaults back to first option.

```
                 <%=Html.DropDownList("MovieType", new List<SelectListItem>
                     {
                        new SelectListItem{ Text="Kids", Value = "Kids" }, 
                        new SelectListItem{ Text="Adults", Value = "Adults" }

                     }, new { onchange = "GetGenre()" })%>
```

Javascript

```
function GetGenre()
{   
    var e = document.getElementById("MovieType");
    var SelValue = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;

    if (SelValue == "Kids")
        window.location.href = "";
    else
        window.location.href = "";    

}
```

Edit:

I have two controllers in MVC3, KidsController and AdultsController.. I want to route to each controller based on what is picked...

Comment: can u show code for this function GetGenre()

Comment: I added the function to OP.. thanks

Comment: Why have you got window.location.href = "" in your JavaScript? This will reload the page hence why you lose the selected value

Comment: I am just trying this out.. I see what you are saying.. is there a better way to navigate to a different action/controller based on the dropdown pick? I want each selection to go to a different controller and action method..

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? If someone selects Kids - is there a method on your controller called Kids? so it would go to /Controller/Kids?

Comment: Yes.. there is a Controller for kids and controller for Adults .. based on selection, I want to route the page to that controller/method

Comment: KidsController/Index and AdultsController/Index - I want to route to these based on selection change.

Comment: Then you can still do what you were doing just set the href to something like window.location.href = SelValue + "Controller/Index"; But as this sends to a new page - if you want to have the correct item in the drop down you will need to do select this manually somehow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  <%=Html.DropDownList("MovieType", new List<SelectListItem>
                     {
                        new SelectListItem{ Text="Kids", Value = "Kids" }, 
                        new SelectListItem{ Text="Adults", Value = "Adults" }

                     }, new { @id = "ddlGetGenre" })%>


    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#ddlGetGenre').val($.cookies('ddlGetGenre'));

        $('#ddlGetGenre').on('change', function () {
            $.cookies('ddlGetGenre', $(this).val());
            if ($(this).val() === "Kids")
                window.location.href = "";
            else
                window.location.href = "";
        });
    });
```

Comment: Please see my response above to Kevin Main.. is there a way to do this without using window.location.href.. and route it to different controller/action based on the drop down selection?

Comment: Why do you want to Control what Route someone goes to in javascript in your MVC project?  This should really be done in a controller.

Comment: And the controller can do: if formVar = kids return View("Kids") else return View("Adult").

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you post your form to a controller which can then look at the value you picked for the form field, and redirect you to /kids?MovieType=Kids or /adult?MovieType=Adult.  Then your onchange would just be form.submit().  That follows the Post, Redirect, Get method.